# Force Mount Samsung 970 SSD in linux

Tags: linux, ssd, nvme, samsung-ssd

My OS NVME SSD drive went into "Read Only" mode once the "Available Spare" threshold was hit.  The superblock seems to be bad, but I'm pretty sure most of the drive is otherwise OK.  What magical combination of mount commands can convince it to mount the drive in read-only mode for browsing the files?

Is there a way to get it out of read-only mode and reduce the available spare threshold so it will work normally for a little while longer?  (It went read-only when 10% spare was hit.  So it should have plenty of headroom for emergency fixing and recovery.)

Alternatively, will dd still manage to read everything off and put it on another NVME drive?

I had this problem on another machine and I was able to make an image with testdisk, but this drive uses LVM partitioning so testdisk is having troubles reading it like it read the first one.

Comment: What file system do you have on the ssd? You can use ``dumpe2fs` for ext or `xfs_db` for xfs to find the alternate superblock.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is ext4, default for a Mint 20 install.